# How to sort a large hashmap on value in a memory efficient way?

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, hashmap

I am working on a project and I end up with a large hashmap, and now i am trying to sort it by values.

```
ArrayList<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> entries = new ArrayList<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>(BloomFilter.map.entrySet());
```

But when I do this, I get an OutOfMemoryError.

Is there any way to prevent this?

Edit:This my if it's in the bloomfilter function

```
    hash1 =  MurmurHash2.hash32(genom);
    hash2 =  genom.hashCode();
    inList = true;

    for (int i = 0; i < k-1 ; i++) {

        hashedGenom = ( hash1 + hash2 * i) % a.size();
        hashedGenom = CheckForNegative(hashedGenom);

        if(!(a.get(hashedGenom))){

            a.set(hashedGenom);
            inList = false;
        } 
    }

    return inList;
```

This is my where im doing bloom filter:

```
        if(CheckIfThere(s, k, fBitset)){

        //  System.out.println("var");
        val = map.get(s);

        if(val != null){
            map.put(s, map.get(s) + 1);
            //map.remove(s);
            //map.put(s, new Integer(val + 1));
        }else{


            map.put(s,1);

        }
```

I am basically, getting the string and send it to CheckIfThere and if it gets true i am putting it to hashmap.

Comment: How large is large? Are you giving the VM a large enough heap?

Comment: What does `BloomFilter.map.entrySet()` do?

Comment: Collections.sort(entries, new Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(Entry<String, Integer> first, Entry<String, Integer> second) {

     return second.getValue() - first.getValue();
    }
   });

Comment: We've all read the docs. You need to tell give us more details. Especially about the bloomfilter implementation that appears to be holding a map of entries? That doesn't really make sense for a Boom filter.

Comment: I use bloomfilter for frequency and in that hash map there are key pair values which my bloomfilter says these elements are already in the list so i get them and increment their value and put it in a hashmap.In this case bloomfilter.map

Comment: Can we see some source for this stuff? And how many elements are we talking about here?

Comment: It is a little long, but i can try what im trying to do, i am bloomfiltering millions of strings and then use it to count the frequency afterwards.So i am holding a bitset  size of 9999999 for bloom filter, and then checking putting these to a hashmap for counting, but since map is organized for keys and i need the sort of values, i finally put it in a collection and it is the point where i get outofmemory

Comment: You probably need to write a [MCVE] for anyone to understand what you're attempting. 10 million strings doesn't really seem like that many. It's also not clear exactly how you're using the filter - you're presumably pre-seeding it with some strings you want to count and then applying the filter to a bunch of other strings and counting the ones that match. But again, these tails need to go into your question.

Comment: Guess it is okay now?@pvg

Comment: Can you help me with that?@pvg

Answer (score 1):

there are several algorithm to resolve it

but i think the easiest way is using database.

you can insert all the values into mysql/oracle/sql server/postgres ... and then

```
select xxxx from xxx order by xxx
```

if you worried about the database is big and hard to deploy, have a try of [sqlite](http://sqlite.org/)

Comment: It ıs a console application and i think i should not be using database

Comment: Please don't take database as the database you think, sqlite is just a library of **external sort algorithm** within a SQL interface. and the **external sort algorithm** is what exactly you need :-)